# Is there an easier way to create a linked list with the given structures?

Tags: c, linked-list

I tried doing it with a for loop but I had no success. This is my current implementation which creates a linked list with 6 elements, but I'm sure there's a way to do it with a loop because my code is very tedious.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#inlcude <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    typedef struct _node {
        int data;
        struct _node * next;
    } node_t;

    typedef struct {
        node_t * head;
        node_t * tail;
    } LL_t;

    LL_t* L = malloc(sizeof(LL_t));

    L->head=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    L->head->data=0;

    L->head->next=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    L->head->next->data=1;

    L->head->next->next=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    L->head->next->next->data=2;

    L->head->next->next->next=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    L->head->next->next->next->data=3;

    L->head->next->next->next->next=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    L->head->next->next->next->next->data=4;

    L->head->next->next->next->next->next=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    L->head->next->next->next->next->next->data=5;

    L->head->next->next->next->next->next->next=NULL;
    L->tail=L->head->next->next->next->next->next;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my for loop that didn't work.

```
node_t* cur = L->head;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    cur = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    cur->data = i;
    printf("%d\n", cur->data);
    if (i == 5) {
        cur->next = NULL;
        L->tail = cur;
        break;
    }
    cur = cur->next;
}
```

Comment: why loop didn't work? google Llist implementations (in C) there should be plenty.

Comment: We need to know why loop didn't worked out for you.

Comment: If you can show us the loop you wrote the question will become more descriptive

Comment: I'm not a C person, but in most languages I think you could write an add function which would also return a reference to the next node in the list.  So, you wouldn't have to use such ugly chaining when building out your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will loop and create however many nodes you specify :

```
int num_nodes = 6;
node_t *L = NULL;
node_t *n;
node_t *tail = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++) {
    n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    if (n == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    // fill in new node
    n->data = i;
    n->next = NULL;

    // save pointers to the first node we create
    if (L == NULL) {
        // save head pointer
        L = n;

        // save tail pointer
        tail = n;
    } else {
        // link node into list, move tail pointer to newly created node
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to output this it doesn't work with my old implementation which was: node_t* cur = L->head and then running that through a for loop and printing cur->data and incrementing cur to cur=cur->next

Comment: I put this together in a file I had that had linked list code in it, so you will need to massage it a little to match your code.  Likely just replace my `L` with `L->head` and my `tail` with `L->tail`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding sequential numbers, a very simple loop would do the trick: in fact, replacing `cur` with `L->head` in your implementation would fix the problem.

However, a more general approach would be to use functions, the primary vehicle of code reuse in C. You would need to move `typedef`s out of the `main`, and write functions `addHead`, `addTail`, `deleteHead` and `deleteTail`:

```
void addTail(LL_t *list, int val) {
    LL_t *n = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    n->data = val;
    n->next = NULL;
    if (list->tail) {
        list->tail->next = n;
    }
    list->tail = n;
    if (!list->head) {
        list->head = n;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `addTail` in your `main`, with or without a loop.

Comment: @4386427 Right, thank you.